# Git remove files locally but keep them in remote repository

Tags: git

So I've tried several approaches and none seem to be working to achieve a seemingly simples thing.

I had to move a lot of images from my local pc to my web server and I used git for that, now I want to delete them from my pc but keep them on the web server.

I tried adding the image folder to .gitignore and ran `git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>` and also `git update-index --skip-worktree <filename>`, but whenever I go and delete the file from my local repository and do `git status` under "changes to be committed" it has the "deleted" entry and if I push and then pull on the web server the file is removed.

I just want to keep the image files on the remote repository while being able to clear them from my local development machine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+delete+file+locally+keeping+remote

Comment: Try sparse checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+sparse+checkout